# SPF record for Gmail?

Tags: domain-name-system, gmail, spf

I have DNS, with a SPF TXT record, configured for a domain name. The primary user of the domain name now needs to be able to send both from our SMTP servers, and also from her GMail account. I've seen all the information about adding "include:_spf.google.com" to the SPF TXT record, but, as I look into it, it appears that record is outdated.

In particular, I had the user send me a test message, and note that it was:

```
Received: from mail-la0-f50.google.com (mail-la0-f50.google.com [209.85.215.50])
```

However, _spf.google.com doesn't list that IP address:

```
$ dig +short _spf.google.com txt
"v=spf1 ip4:216.239.32.0/19 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.249.80.0/20 ip4:72.14.192.0/18   
ip4:209.85.128.0/17 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip4:74.125.0.0/16 ip4:64.18.0.0/20 
ip4:207.126.144.0/20 ip4:173.194.0.0/16 ?all"
```

(Note that a 209.85.21**8**.0 network is listed, but not 209.85.21**5**.0.)

Is there a better way to enable sending from GMail? This user sends to at least one recipient with a strict SPF policy that bounces mail not from a designated host...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

209.85.215.50 falls within 209.85.128.0/17, so Google's record is correct:

```
% ipcalc 209.85.128.0/17 | grep Host
HostMin:   209.85.128.1         11010001.01010101.1 0000000.00000001
HostMax:   209.85.255.254       11010001.01010101.1 1111111.11111110
```

Answer (score 0):

Google set ?all, so [mails from other IPs should not be outright rejected](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax). The result of the SPF check should be "neutral" and message should be accepted.

Comment: Since Google's policy is being included the `?all` doesn't have an effect.

Comment: Damn Terminal, thx for the comment that SPF check should be "neutral", I got confused and thought that my SPF record was not set correctly, but it is a relief when you say this is standard...

Comment: PS: I am not the same Chris who asked the question ;)